# Acceder a los params del context desde getStaticProps en una pagina estática

Tags: javascript, nextjs

Estoy en una ruta estática con parametros `(/search?doa=...&dod=...)` y quisiera obtenerlos en `ctx.params`.

Cuando imprimo mi `ctx` es un objeto con las propiedades `locale`,`locales` y `defaultLocales`, todas en `undefined`. Y no tengo mi propiedad `params`.

Si agrego `getStaticPaths` me devuelve un error porque la pagina no es dinamica. Yo quisiera analizar los parametros antes de mandar el return desde `getStaticProps`. Es posible esto?

```
export const getStaticProps = async ctx => {
  const url = `${process.env.CW_BASE_URL}/search_winter-rentals` || null;

  console.log("Context ", ctx);
  return {
    props: {
      pageData: {
        canonicalUrl: url,
      },
      isSearchPage: true,
      isWinterSearch: true,
    },
    revalidate: parseInt(process.env.STATIC_REGEN_TIME || "240", 10),
  };
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

las paginas estaticas que usan `getStaticProps` **son creadas al momento del Build**, no hay forma de que se sepan los query params en ese momento.
Para obtener los parametros tendras que usar `useRoter()`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

//...

const {query} = useRouter()
```

Comment: Es lo que termine haciendo. No se porque estaba bastante seguro que esos datos deberian estar dentro del ctx, me la estoy confundiendo con otra funcion y no se con cual jaja. Efectivamente la docu dice lo que vos decis, gracias!